# How do I make BeautifulSoup ignore any indents in original HTML when getting text

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I think, I basically want the reverse of what the `prettify()` function does.

When one has HTML code (excerpt) like:

```
      <p>
        Test text with something in it
        Test text with something in it
        <i>and italic text</i> inside that text.
        Test text with something in it.
      </p>
      <p>
        Next paragraph with more text.
      </p>
```

How can one get the text inside without the line breaks and indentations? This all while looping recursively over the tree to also be able to cover nested tags?

The result after parsing and processing should be something like:

```
Test text with something in it Test text with something in it \textit{and italic text} inside that text. Test text with something in it.

Next paragraph with more text.
```

Also, for further processing, it would be good to get the content of italic tags separately in Python.

That means (simplified; in reality, I want to call `pylatex` functions to compose a document):

```
string result = ""
for child in soup.children:
    for subchild in child.children:
        # Some processing
        result += subchild.string
```

This should also work for more complex examples, obviously:

```
      <p>
        Test text with something in it
        Test text with <i>something <b>in
        <em>it</em> test</b></i>
        <i>and <em>italic</em> text</i> inside that text.
        Test text with something in it.
      </p>
```

Most of this is not that complicated, but how can one deal correctly with line breaks and spaces for the nested text?

The browser seems to render this correctly.

If not possible with BeautifulSoup, another Python library doing this is also fine.

I was quite shocked that this isn't dealt with by default in BeautifulSoup and I also didn't find any function doing what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lxml to do it. Compared with beautifulsoup, it will be more free in some aspects：

```py
import re
import textwrap
from lxml import etree

html_str = """
  <p>
    Test text with something in it
    Test text with something in it
    <i>and italic text</i> inside that text.
    Test text with something in it.
  </p>
  <p>
    Next paragraph with more text.
  </p>
"""
root = etree.HTML(html_str)

# customize special element processing logic
handle_tag_dict = {"i": lambda x: "\\textit{%s}" % x}
# tags that do not require additional line breaks
not_lb_tags = ["i"]

result = ""
for elem in root.iterdescendants():
    tag = elem.tag
    if result and tag not in not_lb_tags:
        result += "\n"

    # not None, then remove indent from paragraph text, replace \n with white space and strip
    if (text := elem.text) and (
        text := textwrap.dedent(text).replace("\n", " ").strip()
    ):
        # add spaces to separate text
        if tag in not_lb_tags:
            result += " "
        # convert excess space into a single
        text = re.sub("\s{2,}", " ", text)
        if tag in handle_tag_dict:
            text = handle_tag_dict[tag](text)
        result += text

    if (tail := elem.tail) and (
        tail := textwrap.dedent(tail).replace("\n", " ").strip()
    ):
        result += " "
        tail = re.sub("\s{2,}", " ", tail)
        result += tail

print(result)
```

Print:

```
Test text with something in it Test text with something in it \textit{and italic text} inside that text. Test text with something in it.
Next paragraph with more text.
```

**Use recursion to handle nested structures:**

```
import re
import textwrap
from lxml import etree

html_str = """
  <p>
    Test text with something in it
    Test text with <i>something <b>in
    <em>it</em> test</b></i>
    <i>and <em>italic</em> text</i> inside that text.
    Test text with something in it.
  </p>
    <p>
        Next paragraph with more text.
  </p>
"""
root = etree.HTML(html_str)

# customize special element processing logic
handle_tag_dict = {
    "i": lambda x: "\\textit{%s}" % x,
    "b": lambda x: "\\textbf{%s}" % x,
}

# https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#Elements
# https://github.com/gawel/pyquery/blob/0a7cbf0c21132727d0ebf6fb5b78120d4a037221/pyquery/text.py#L5
INLINE_TAGS = {
    'a', 'abbr', 'acronym', 'b', 'bdo', 'big', 'br', 'button', 'cite',
    'code', 'dfn', 'em', 'i', 'img', 'input', 'kbd', 'label', 'map',
    'object', 'q', 'samp', 'script', 'select', 'small', 'span', 'strong',
    'sub', 'sup', 'textarea', 'time', 'tt', 'var'
}

def get_text(elem: etree) -> str:
    result = ""
    tag = elem.tag

    if text := elem.text:
        # remove indent from paragraph text, replace \n with white space and strip
        text = textwrap.dedent(text).replace("\n", " ").strip()
        # convert excess space into a single
        text = re.sub("\s{2,}", " ", text)
    else:
        text = ""

    children = elem.getchildren()
    if len(children) > 0:
        for child in children:
            text += get_text(child)

    if tag in handle_tag_dict:
        text = handle_tag_dict[tag](text)

    if tag in INLINE_TAGS:
        result += " " + text
    else:
        result += "\n" + text

    if (tail := elem.tail) and (
        tail := textwrap.dedent(tail).replace("\n", " ").strip()
    ):
        result += " "
        tail = re.sub("\s{2,}", " ", tail)
        result += tail

    return result


ret = get_text(root).lstrip()
print(ret)
```

Print:

```
Test text with something in it Test text with \textit{something \textbf{in it test}} \textit{and italic text} inside that text. Test text with something in it.
Next paragraph with more text.
```

Comment: Similar logic might be possible with BeautifulSoup, I think. I first thought that `iterdescendants()` might work differently for `lxml`. Unfortunately, as it seems, this method fails right now if there are nested tags with more depth than in the example. I added a more complex example to the question.

Comment: That may require layer-by-layer recursion to achieve.

Comment: Exactly what I think. Possibly that is partly dealt with in another answer already.

Comment: Yes, although it may be a bit troublesome, I think it is feasible to combine the current solutions. Good luck.

Comment: I have provided a solution for recursively processing nested structures, which may be feasible, for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.get_text()` (with `strip=True` and correct `separator=` parameters):

```py
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
      <p>
        Test text with something in it
        Test text with something in it
        <i>and italic text</i> inside that text.
        Test text with something in it.
      </p>
      <p>
        Next paragraph with more text.
      </p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")


def my_get_text(tag):
    t = tag.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
    return re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", t)


# replace all <i></i> with \textit{ ... }
for i in soup.select("i"):
    i.replace_with("\\textit{{{}}}".format(i.text))

for p in soup.select("p"):
    print(my_get_text(p))
```

Prints:

```
Test text with something in it Test text with something in it \textit{and italic text} inside that text. Test text with something in it.
Next paragraph with more text.
```

---

EDIT: Using recursion:

```py
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag

html_text = """\
      <p>
        Test text with something in it
        Test text with something in it
        <i>and italic text</i> inside that text.
        Test text with something in it.
      </p>
      <p>
        Next paragraph with more text.
      </p>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")


def my_get_text(tag):
    t = tag.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
    return re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", t)


def get_text(tag):
    s = []
    for c in tag.contents:
        match c:
            case NavigableString():
                if c := my_get_text(c):
                    s.append(c)
            case Tag() if c.name == "p":
                yield from get_text(c)
            case Tag() if c.name == "i":
                s.append("\\textit{{{}}}".format(c.text))
    if s:
        yield s


for t in get_text(soup):
    print(" ".join(t))
```

Prints:

```
Test text with something in it Test text with something in it \textit{and italic text} inside that text. Test text with something in it.
Next paragraph with more text.
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll need to see whether this will help with my use case. Possibly, I simplified the example too much. What if I wanted to process the italic text separately?

Comment: @clel Are you converting HTML to Markdown? Maybe this will help: https://pypi.org/project/markdownify/ ? But I'm sure there are more libraries for that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not converting to Markdown; that was only for the easy example. The goal is to convert to LaTeX, although for versatility, some generalized answer might be best.

Comment: `p.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")` doesn't work for multiline indented text. At least when I tested, it only worked on the first line of a paragraph, not multiple.

Comment: @clel Maybe you can edit your question and put there othe example + required output?

Comment: I just did, as I saw that your answer works for my example. I constructed a more complicated example now.

Comment: @clel Well, then you can use `re` to process the text further. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! For substitution directly in the HTML, that works. And possibly that is also the route that I'll need to go. But when looping over a document, like in my again updated question, is there also a way to achieve this? Probably more find and replace, I guess.

Comment: I guess, the easiest way for that would be to preformat the text for BeautifulSoup. So I opened another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77183906/python-robustly-remove-all-line-breaks-and-indentations-from-html-replacing-so.

Comment: @clel I've updated my answer with recursion approach.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [Pyquery](https://pyquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and its `text()` method.

```
from pyquery import PyQuery

doc = PyQuery("""\
      <p>
        Test text with something in it
        Test text with something in it
        <i>and italic text</i> inside that text.
        Test text with something in it.
      </p>
      <p>
        Next paragraph with more text.
      </p>
""")
print(doc.text())
#Just italics:
print([i.text() for i in doc.items('i')])
```

By default the `text()` method squashes new lines, which is what you want.
If you want to preserve new lines, use the parameter `squash_space=False`

Comment: I played around with it a bit. Unfortunately, I couldn't yet find a way how to process the `i` items inside an element and create a modified text from it. Possibly it works using the `contents()` method; not sure.

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped your original question, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). You may consider asking a new question for what you've tried with italic items and didn't work.

Comment: But that is already included in my original question. And your answer doesn't cover that aspect right now.