# Python: Robustly remove all line breaks and indentations from HTML (replacing some inside tags with spaces as the browser would do for rendering)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, format

As BeautifulSoup doesn't seem to work well with indented content and breaks inside tags (also see [How do I make BeautifulSoup ignore any indents in original HTML when getting text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77183750/how-do-i-make-beautifulsoup-ignore-any-indents-in-original-html-when-getting-tex)), I'd like to preprocess my HTML file.

Something like:

```
      <p>
        Test text with something in it
        Test text with something in it
        <i>and italic text</i> inside that text.
        Test text with something in it.
      </p>
      <p>
        Next paragraph with more text.
      </p>
```

should turn into:

```
<p>Test text with something in it Test text with something in it <i>and italic text</i> inside that text. Test text with something in it.</p><p>Next paragraph with more text.</p>
```

Is there a library for this, or should I use some own function like find and replace with a regex pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

html_text = """\
      <p>
        Test text with something in it
        Test text with something in it
        <i>and italic text</i> inside that text.
        Test text with something in it.
      </p>
      <p>
        Next paragraph with more text.
      </p>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")


def my_get_text(tag):
    t = tag.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
    return re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", t)


for tag in soup.select("p"):
    for c in tag.contents:
        if isinstance(c, NavigableString):
            c.replace_with(my_get_text(c))

for tag in soup.select("i"):
    tag.replace_with(
        BeautifulSoup(" <i>{}</i> ".format(my_get_text(tag)), "html.parser")
    )

print(str(soup).strip())
```

Prints:

```html
<p>Test text with something in it Test text with something in it <i>and italic text</i> inside that text. Test text with something in it.</p>
<p>Next paragraph with more text.</p>
```

Comment: Note that now the tags are in new lines (which might be okay, not sure) but also there is now no space before and after the `i` tags. So rendering this in a browser will not give the same result, I think. Also, now this is not generalized to work for any HTML, but only for specific tags.

Comment: @clel I've put spaces before/after `<i>`

Comment: @clel Also, you must specify how you want to handle which tag. I guess `<i>` tag is handled differently as `<b>` etc.

Comment: Basically, I think that I want something like this (in Python): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372807/how-to-convert-multiline-html-code-to-single-line-html-code. Maybe, my question is also a duplicate of another one, not sure.